# accessing to R studio server in local network

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am beginner with R studio server.

I installed it on a machine in the local network of my university.

The machine has then a local ip address: 192.168.x.x .

I can access to R through web browser in the university (local net).

My question is:

How can I access to R server, from outside (for eg my home ?) 
since 192.168.x.x is in the lan only. Should I do it through a gateway? any configurations I've missed?

Please help me.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the external IP of the network to access remotely, but you'll also need something like port forwarding to redirect your connection to the server itself. Most big organisations won't be willing to take on the security holes this opens up, but you can try convincing your IT department.

The other option is through a VPN, which I'd say you've got more chance with.